# mat-select inside a dialog not selecting properly

Tags: angular, select, dialog

I'm trying to implement a functionality where the user is prompted a dialog where he's asked to selected a value from a drop-down menu and confirm his choice with an "OK" button. I'm using Angular Material to achieve this. But I have a problem with the mat-select inside the dialog as it does not show or return the selected option.

Here's my dialog HTML code

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Saving choice ... </h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>Please selected an option</p>
  <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Which option?" [(ngModel)]="selectedChoice" >
  <mat-option>None</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of data.options">{{opt.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
 <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()" >Back</button>
 <button mat-button (click)="confirmSelection()" cdkFocusInitial >Save</button>
</div>
```

And this is the Component ts code :

```
export class SaveChoiceDialog {

   selectedChoice : string;

   constructor(
     public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SaveChoiceDialog>,
     @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { options : Option[]}) {}


   onNoClick(): void {
     this.dialogRef.close();
    }

   confirmSelection(): void {
     this.dialogRef.close(this.selectedChoice)
    }

 }
```

So my problem is when I click on the drop-down menu and click on an option it does not show and I the placeholder does not change to the selected value.

I tried following the angular doc and [this tutorial](https://alligator.io/angular/dialogs-angular-material/) but it doesnt seem to work for me... what am I doing wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign value to mat-select `[(ngModel)]="selectedChoice"` with selected value in mat-option.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let opt of data.options" [value]="opt.valueOf">{{opt.name}}</mat-option>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... I feel dumb for missing that :d